# How to run PDAL pipeline with docker

Tags: lidar, pdal, docker

I used to use PDAL with conda environment, and in that time I used pipeline command with the simple:

```
 sudo pdal pipeline -i /Documents/laz2pg.txt
```

And that did the work.
But, now, at the moment, I have to use PDAL which is installed with Docker environment and I have trouble because I don't really know anything about docker. I find out that the command for information is:

```
sudo docker run -v '/home/user/Documents/projectX:/data' pdal/pdal:1.7 pdal info /data/pt.las -p 0
```

But If try analogy to replace pt.las with laz2pg and info with pipeline I get an error that file is not found.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the -v option maps the directory **/data** on the container to the directory **/home/user/Documents/projectX** on your host machine. It's just like having a shared folder with a virtual machine.

That means that when you call

```
pdal info /data/pt.las
```

it's expecting to find a pt.las in the /home/user/Documents/projectX directory. As you won't have put in las2pg in that directory, that's why it's not working when you call info or pipeline on it.

Not personally familiar with PDAL so I'm not sure where the info and pipeline tools live, so check the documentation. It's sometimes the case with docker images that you need to set up a path or environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It made me realized some things. Anyway, now I get another error. I am not sure is it because of docker or this version pdal. With the same text file, data and database I was earlier managed to import lidar data to postgres and now I get the error:
PDAL: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: After I solve this error I will accept your answer, because I am not yet sure it is related to this topic.

Comment: see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31249112/5158630) - assuming you intend to run postgres on your host rather than in the container.

Comment: I succeeded! I put in the command that is net=host. I will my line of code write as an answer, and will accept your answer, because, you really helped me. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

So the line which does the job is:

```
sudo docker run --net=host -v /home/user/Documents/projectX:/data pdal/pdal:1.7 pdal pipeline /data/laz2pg.txt
```